# Open tcp/udp ports with no socket

Tags: c, networking, tcp, network-programming, winpcap

I have started working with winpcap, and i got a funny situation with tcp/udp ports. I wrote a packet forwarder, that sniff on interface and forward packets from specified ports. I do not open the ports because i sniff directly from interface. The problem is that the tcp/ip stack answers RST,ACK on closed tcp port, and an ICMP Destination unreachable on closed UDP port.

I need to solve that issue in a way that closed port won't answer anything that will interrupt the conversation.

Is there a way i can drop packets from reaching to tcp/ip stack?
Can i disable the automatic answers of RST,ACK and destination unreachable?
Can i listen on tcp that wont replay a SYN ACK on a SYN packet?

Hope i got myself clear, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions that I can think of:

- Don't use your PC IP address, use a different IP address, and implement a small ARP reply logic, that's less headache that trying to prevent packets from reaching the OS.
- Use the WinDivert driver https://www.reqrypt.org/windivert.html I know it can make the OS drop packets, but not sure if that covers the SYN packets as well.

Comment: Well, you think i can open the tcp port without it sending syn-ack while listening? I just want the port the be unresponsive, not sending rst-ack nor syn-ack.

Comment: You may be able to prevent it from sending syn-ack, but you won't be be able to prevent it from sending rst using socket api. The only way you **may** be able to prevent it from sending rst is using a driver/firewall such as WinDivert.